# nutch and solr for multiple domains

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using nutch 1.7 and solr 4.6 to create a search engine for two website. In the seed.txt file, I have:

```
http://domain1.com/
http://domain2.com/
```

I run this

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/ -depth 1
```

Here is my Solr schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->
<!--
    Description: This document contains Solr 4.x schema definition to
    be used with Solr integration currently build into Nutch.
    This schema is not minimal, there are some useful field type definitions left,
    and the set of fields and their flags (indexed/stored/term vectors) can be
    further optimized depending on needs.  See
    http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/example/solr/conf/schema.xml?view=markup
    for more info.
-->

<schema name="nutch" version="1.5">

  <types>

    <!-- The StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored verbatim. -->
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>

        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- Less flexible matching, but less false matches.  Probably not ideal for product names,
         but may be good for SKUs.  Can insert dashes in the wrong place and still match. -->
    <fieldType name="text_en_splitting_tight" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- this filter can remove any duplicate tokens that appear at the same position - sometimes
             possible with WordDelimiterFilter in conjuncton with stemming. -->
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- Just like text_general except it reverses the characters of
     each token, to enable more efficient leading wildcard queries. -->
    <fieldType name="text_general_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"
           maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldtype name="phonetic" stored="false" indexed="true" class="solr.TextField" >
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.DoubleMetaphoneFilterFactory" inject="false"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldtype>

    <fieldtype name="payloads" stored="false" indexed="true" class="solr.TextField" >
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" encoder="float"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldtype>

    <!-- lowercases the entire field value, keeping it as a single token.  -->
    <fieldType name="lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="url" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>


    <fieldType name="text_path" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- since fields of this type are by default not stored or indexed,
         any data added to them will be ignored outright.  --> 
    <fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" multiValued="true" class="solr.StrField" />

 </types>

 <fields>
    <field name="id" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>

    <!-- core fields -->
    <field name="segment" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
    <field name="digest" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
    <field name="boost" type="float" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

    <!-- fields for index-basic plugin -->
    <field name="host" type="url" stored="false" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="site" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="url" type="url" stored="true" indexed="true" required="true"/>
    <!-- stored=true for highlighting, use term vectors  and positions for fast highlighting -->
    <field name="content" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="title" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="cache" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
    <field name="tstamp" type="date" stored="true" indexed="false"/>

    <!-- catch-all field -->
    <field name="text" type="text_general" stored="false" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>

    <!-- fields for index-anchor plugin -->
    <field name="anchor" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true"
        multiValued="true"/>

    <!-- fields for index-more plugin -->
    <field name="type" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="contentLength" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
    <field name="lastModified" type="date" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
    <field name="date" type="tdate" stored="true" indexed="true"/>

    <!-- fields for languageidentifier plugin -->
    <field name="lang" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>

    <!-- fields for subcollection plugin -->
    <field name="subcollection" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>

    <!-- fields for feed plugin (tag is also used by microformats-reltag)-->
    <field name="author" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="tag" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="feed" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="publishedDate" type="date" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="updatedDate" type="date" stored="true" indexed="true"/>

    <!-- fields for creativecommons plugin -->
    <field name="cc" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
 </fields>
 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
 <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>

  <!-- copyField commands copy one field to another at the time a document
        is added to the index.  It's used either to index the same field differently,
        or to add multiple fields to the same field for easier/faster searching.  -->

 <copyField source="content" dest="text"/>
 <copyField source="url" dest="text"/>
 <copyField source="title" dest="text"/>
 <copyField source="anchor" dest="text"/>
 <copyField source="author" dest="text"/>

</schema>
```

when I do a search like that:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=keyword&wt=json&indent=true&fq=site:domain1.com
```

The response is that

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"keyword",
      "wt":"json",
      "fq":"site:domain1.com"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Do any one know how to filter the result by domain/site?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to do to make this work

1. Ensure that the domain in your filter is exactly like the domain that is stored in the field site. This is because you used for that field the type string which doesn't do fuzzy matching.
2. Format your characters to their html equivalent
3. Your domain string needs to be in quotes ""

Example query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=keyword&fq=site%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fdomain1.com%22&wt=json&indent=true
```

Where the site field in my index is http://domain1.com